# Triple composite key in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a use case where I want 3 level composite key.
For eg.
Rollnumber:class:friendsRollNumber

I would want to query "Get all friends for a particular roll number and a class"

I could not find sufficient examples over net to use composite keys and range scans over it together.

Currently, I am doing the following.

> ```
> byte[]rowkey = Bytes.add(Bytes.tobytes("myrollnumber"),Bytes.tobytes("myClass"),Bytes.tobytes("myFriendsRollNumber"))
> ```

This is the way I form row key .
Will it select region server based on myRollNumber and myClass ? If not How can I do that ?

Also , For range scan , what is the correct way to use it. I am doing it in the following way. I am still in process of writing the code , so have not tested it.

> ```
> Scan s = new Scan();
> Filter f  = New PrefixFilter(Bytes.tobytes("myrollnumber"),Bytes.tobytes("class"))
> s.setFilter(f)
> ```

Is the above way correct to scan as per my requirement ?

Also , how to get the individual parts of rowKey from the scanner ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] prefix=Bytes.toBytes("rollnumber" + "class");
Scan scan = new Scan(prefix));
PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(prefix);
scan.addFilter(prefixFilter);
ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Comment: This does not answer my complete question. as in how the Regionserver will be selected while inserting row key. I want it to be selected based on roll number and class so that range becomes efficient for me

Comment: This code snippet will give you all the friends data. Region server will be selected based on your row key. HBase decides RS based on the chronological order to maintain the ranges of keys on each RS.  If it is sequential then can be a problem otherwise no issue.

Comment: My query will be , get all friends of a roll number of a particular class. SO I don't want the query to span across region servers. Is there a way in hbase so that I can select the forst 2 parts of row key as my partition key which selects region servers

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use start stop row feature of Scan. You do not need a filter.

```
byte[]startRow= Bytes.add(Bytes.tobytes("search_rollnumber"),Bytes.tobytes("myClass"));
byte[]stopRow= Bytes.add(Bytes.tobytes("search_rollnumber"),Bytes.tobytes("myClass"));
stopRow[stopRow.length - 1]++;
Scan s = new Scan(startRow, stopRow);
```

Using this scan you will get all rows starting with search_rollnumberMyClass.
I am not sure you use : in your rowkey. But i think you should if both rollnumber and class are represented as integer.